# System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 400 (Bad Request) OnceSingleAsync FIREBASE

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin

I'm try to retrive data from firebase but I got this error if I add `orderBy()` and `EquatTo()`

Here is my code:

```
var firebase = new FirebaseClient("https://xxx-xxx.xxxx.com/");
var _item = await firebase.Child("Pc and Laptops")
              .OrderBy("ProductID")
              .EqualTo("ID")
              .WithAuth("someauth")
              .OnceSingleAsync<object>();
```

Here is my database scheme:

[image: here is my database scheme]

Answer (score 0):

You want to sort data that retrieving from firebase, from FireBase document, you can see there are three way to sort data,  OrderByChild(),OrderByKey(),OrderByValue().

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/retrieve-data

So you can use OrderByChild() in your query sentence.